# NetBeans IDE 7.4 "Unable to download any plugins"

Tags: netbeans, proxy

Unable to connect to the NetBeans Distribution because of Zero sized file reported at http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz?unique=NB_EXTIDE_GFMOD_GROOVY_JAVA_JC_MOB_TOMCAT_WEBCOMMON_WEBEE09d50e68d-19e4-4755-a252-3762258d293a_15b57b09-85c8-4ae4-a61a-0da8cc9ee8d4

Check your proxy settings or try again later.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I doubt if you can resolve this issue. NetBeans 7.4 was released over 8 years ago, and is no longer supported. There have been many releases of NetBeans since then. Is there anything requiring you to use such an old version?

Comment: Yes, for the college project.

Comment: OK, understood. On NetBeans 8.2 I tried **Tools > Plugins > Settings > Add**  to add your raw URL (i.e.  `http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz`) as an update center and it works fine, showing that it contains four plugins: *NetBeans Plugin Development*, *Java Card*, *JavaFX2 Support* and *Mobility*. Does that also work for you? If not, then check that you are not having problems due to VPN, firewall, virus checker, etc.

Comment: I can see the installed plugins. But when I'm trying to add a raw URL (i.e http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz) it says "Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic."

Comment: Well there is your answer: you have a network or environment issue that is preventing you from downloading the plugins file. Why?...because that plugin URL worked fine for me, and I just tried it again and it still works (using Firefox). The plugin URL is not the problem. Perhaps try using a different browser? But please note that questions relating to download problems are usually off topic for Stack Overflow. If you remain stuck then you might [try raising your download problem on superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead.